# Weak Lefschetz theorem in weighted projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In [Weighted projective varieties](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eidolga/weighted82.pdf), Igor Dolgachev  obtains in Corollary 4.2.2 that for a quasismooth weighted projective hypersurface $X$ in weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}$ of dimension $n$,
$$H^{i}(X,\mathbb{C})\to H^{i+1}(\mathbb{P},\mathbb{C}),$$
is an isomorphism if $i\not=n-1$ and is an epimorphism if $i=n-1$.

However, the map here seems to go in the wrong direction, and the $+1$ shift is a bit strange since it is not there in the usual weak Lefschetz theorem. So is this result really correct?

Comment: This is a typo of course, replace $i$ by $i+1$. The map is the Gysin map, dual to the restriction map.

Comment: @abx thanks, that clears it up.

Comment: By the way, there is a more serious error in Dolgachev's text: he missed one condition on the degree and weights, called *well-formed* in the reference below. For instance, his formula for the dualizing sheaf is incorrect without that condition. See A. R. Iano-Fletcher, *Working with weighted complete intersections*, in "Explicit
Birational Geometry of 3-Folds", London Math. Soc. Lecture Note
Series 281.

Comment: @abx Thanks a lot for letting me know! I wouldn't have noticed that if you hadn't.

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed I think it took some time before that problem was noticed.